# Power BI - Filter from tables using wildcards

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, wildcard, powerbi-desktop

I am a Power BI and database rookie and would need some help.
I have two tables:

### **Profitcentre**

| Profitcentre | Profitcentretype |
| --- | --- |
| 6010 | Unit |
| 6011 | Unit |
| 7010 | Unit |
| 7011 | Unit |
| 9000 | Agg |
| 9010 | Agg |
| 9020 | Agg |

"Agg" meaning that it is a profit centre consisting of two or more units together as defined in this table:

### **Profitcentreprofile**

| Profitcentre | Profile |
| --- | --- |
| 6010 | 6010 |
| 6011 | 6011 |
| 7010 | 7010 |
| 7011 | 7011 |
| 9000 | 6% |
| 9010 | 6011 |
| 9010 | 7% |
| 9090 | % |

'%' is used as a wildcard simular to '*' in Windows
How to interpret this is:
6010, 6011, 7010, 7011 consists of only themselves, they are units.
9000 consists of unit 6010 and 6011 ("6%" meaning every Unit starting with '6')
9010 consists of unit 6011, 7010 and 7011 (6011 and 7%)
9090 consists of all units, 6010, 6011, 7010 and 7011 ("%" meaning any unit.)

Each profitcentre of type "Unit" is related to employees, revenue etc. and I need to be able to filter based on Profitcentre. Therefor, I would like to create a table that looks like this:

### **Extended Profitcentreprofile**

| Profitcentre | Profile |
| --- | --- |
| 6010 | 6010 |
| 6011 | 6011 |
| 7010 | 7010 |
| 7011 | 7011 |
| 9000 | 6010 |
| 9000 | 6011 |
| 9010 | 6011 |
| 9010 | 7010 |
| 9010 | 7011 |
| 9090 | 6010 |
| 9090 | 6011 |
| 9090 | 7010 |
| 9090 | 7011 |

If I had a table like this, I could easily use column "Profitcentre" in this new table to filter employees, revenue etc, which is what I want to accomplish.

Now I don't know if creating a new table is the most efficient way. Maybe there is some smart DAX expression that could solve this as well. If you have better ideas please propose.

I don't know where to start, so haven't tried much. Expected result is being able to filter on 'Profitcentre'[Profitcentre].